# Customise WooCommerce [Product] Display

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

What shortcode by WooCommerce can i use to achieve:

Product category (e.g. shoes)
  Product count (e.g. Showing 1–15 of 297 results)
Limit (50 products)
Orderby (for FEATURED products)
Also to display the "Order Dropdown"

I know the base shortcode is [products] , but want to build on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce provides two ways for customising catalogue page:

1. You can use the shortcode [products] with attributes.

The documentation is available by the link https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

2. The catalogue page has a list of hook. You can customise your catalogue page when you add the custom hooks on these actions.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 ); 
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );
```

The documentation is available by the link https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/